# Changing a string in a list of strings

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So basically I have a huge list of strings, for example

```
list = ["hello", "my", "name", "is"]
```

etc...

and I want to ask the user a question, if the user responses with a word that is in my list I want to replace it with "yes". How would I do this, everything that I have tried has failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
# user input in user_input
new_list = [item if item != user_input else "yes" for item in old_list]
```

This replaces anything that's equal to the `user_input` with "yes".

**Tip:** don't shadow the built-in [`list`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Output:

```
>>> old_list = ["hello", "my", "name", "is"] 
>>> user_input = "hello"
>>> new_list = [item if item != user_input else "yes" for item in old_list] 
>>> new_list
['yes', 'my', 'name', 'is']
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this is your list

```
 INPUT_MATCH = 'yes'
 L = ["hello", "my", "name", "is"]
```

You are asking user to input

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter your input")

if user_input in set(L): #reason to convert list to set for less expensive search
    L[L.index(user_input)] = INPUT_MATCH
```